# What is happening when Matlab is starting a "parallel pool"?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Running parallel CPU processes in Matlab starts with the command

```
parpool()
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html), that function:

> [creates] a special job on a pool of workers, and [connects] the MATLAB client to the parallel pool.

This function usually takes a bit of time to execute, on the order of 30 seconds. But in other multi-CPU paradigms like OpenMP, the parallel execution seems totally transparent -- I've never noticed any behavior analogous to what Matlab does (granted I'm not very experienced with parallel programming).

So, what is actually happening between the time that `parpool()` is called and when it finishes executing? What takes so long?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parallel Computing Toolbox enables you to run MATLAB code in parallel using several different paradigms (e.g. jobs and tasks, `parfor`, `spmd`, `parfeval`, batch processing), and to run it either locally (parallelised across cores in your local machine) or remotely (parallelised across machines in a cluster - either one that you own, or one in the cloud).

In any of these cases, the code is run on MATLAB *workers*, which are basically copies of MATLAB without an interactive desktop.

If you're intending to run on a remote cluster, it's likely that these workers will already be started up and ready to run code. If you're intending to run locally, it's possible that you might already have started workers, but maybe you haven't.

Some of constructs above (e.g. jobs and tasks, batch processing) just run the thing you asked for, and the workers then go back to being available for other things (possibly from a different user).

But some of the constructs (e.g. `parfor`, `spmd`) require that the workers on which you intend to run are *reserved* for you for a period of time - partly because they might lie idle for some time and you don't want them taken over by another user, and partly because (unlike with jobs and tasks, or batch processing) they might need to communicate with each other. This is called creating a *worker pool*.

When you run `parpool`, you're telling MATLAB that you want to reserve a pool of workers for yourself, because you're intending to run a construct that requires a worker pool. You can specify as an input argument a cluster profile, which would tell it whether you want to run on a remote cluster or locally.

If you're running on a cluster, `parpool` will send a message to the cluster to reserve some of its (already running) workers for your use.

If you're running locally, `parpool` will ensure that there are enough workers running locally, and then connect them into a pool for you.

The thing that takes 30 seconds is the part where it needs to start up workers, if they're not already running. On Windows, if you watch Task Manager while running `parpool`, you'll see additional copies of MATLAB popping up over those 30 seconds as the workers start (they're actually not MATLAB itself, they're MATLAB workers - you can distinguish them as they'll be using less memory with no desktop).

To compare what MATLAB is doing to OpenMP, note that these MATLAB workers are separate processes, whereas OpenMP creates multiple threads within an existing process.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I do not think that we will ever get to know exactly what MatLab does.

However, to give you some answer, MatLab basically opens additional instances of itself, for it to execute the code on. In order to do this, it first needs to check where the instances should be opened (you can change the cluster from local to whatever else you have access to, e.g. Amazons EC2 cluster). Once the new instances have been opened MatLab then has set the connection from your main window to the instances up.

Notes:

1) It is not recommended to use `parpool` inside a function or script as if it is run while a parallel pool is open it will cast an error. The use of parallel commands e.g. `parfor` will automatically open the instance.

2) `parpool` only have to be executed "once" (before it is shut down), i.e. if you run the code again the instances are already open.

3) If you want to avoid the overhead in your codes, you can create a file called startup.m in the search path of MATLAB, with the command `parpool`, this will automatically start a parallel pool on startup.

4) Vectorizing your code will automatically make it parallelised without the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

A few further details to follow up on @Nicky's answer. Creating a parallel pool involves:

1. Submitting a communicating job to the appropriate cluster
2. This recruits MATLAB worker processes. These processes might be already running (in the case of MJS), or they might need to be started (in the case of `'local'`, and all other cluster types).
3. MPI communication is set up among the workers to support `spmd` (unless you specify "`'SpmdEnabled', false`" while starting the pool - however, this stage isn't usually a performance bottleneck).
4. The MATLAB workers are then connected up to the client so they can do its bidding.

The difference in overhead between `parpool` and something like OpenMP is because `parpool` generally launches additional MATLAB processes - a relatively heavy-weight operation, whereas OpenMP simply creates additional threads within a single process - comparatively light-weight. Also, as @Nicky points out - MATLAB can intrinsically multi-thread some/most vectorised operations - `parpool` is useful for cases where this doesn't happen, or where you have a real multi-node cluster available to run on.